# Match elements from ID table and table with multiple rows of same ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013

I have the following two spreadsheets:

[image: input]

My goal is, on a 3rd spreadsheet, to obtain the table on the right-hand side but only with the IDs that are on the table on the left, i.e.:

[image: output]

Comment: If you are one of the lucky ones, use the `FILTER()` function

Comment: FILTER() is not available in my excel version

Comment: Then I think you will need VBA for this

Comment: Use Power query with `.AddJoinColumn`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick in VBA

```
Sub Pandemic()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long, x As Long, lr As Long
Dim DeleteMe As Range
Dim Flag As Boolean


'Target Values
Dim target
target = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

'Table With All Values
Dim source As Range
lr = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set source = ws.Range("C2:D" & lr)

'Create Copy of Table
source.Copy ws.Range("F2")


For i = 2 To lr

    Flag = False

    For x = LBound(target) To UBound(target)
        If ws.Range("F" & i) = target(x, 1) Then
            Flag = True
        End If
    Next x
    
    If Not Flag Then
        If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, ws.Range("F" & i).Resize(1, 2))
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = ws.Range("F" & i).Resize(1, 2)
        End If
    End If
    
Next i

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.Delete

End Sub
```

---

For reference, these are the ranges I tested with. You will have to update the ranges and sheet references accordingly.

1. Left table includes the target ids
2. Middle table is the full list of values
3. Final table is macro output (removes rows with ID missing from left table)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ranges are "Tables", you can use Power Query:

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="idValTbl"]}[Content],
    tbl1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="idTbl"]}[Content],
    tbl2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{"ID", type text}),
    join = Table.AddJoinColumn(tbl2,"ID",tbl1,"ID","joined"),
    #"Expanded joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(join, "joined", {"Value"}, {"Value"})
in
    #"Expanded joined"
```

Change the table names in lines 2 and 4 to reflect the real table names in your workbook of the table 2 and table 1 shown above.

[image]